# Cross-compiling Go program which uses cgo for Windows using MinGW: link errors

Tags: windows, go, build, tesseract, mingw-w64

I have a problem building my Go app for windows.I am using tesseract ocr in my app, for this i found ***[gosseract](https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract)*** package. When I build it for macos(I use macbook air m1) it builds, but when I try to build it for windows from mac using this command:

> GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 go build -ldflags "-extldflags=-static" -p 4 -v -o bin/app-amd64.exe main.go

I got err:

> command-line-arguments
>
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link:
> running x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ failed: exit status 1
>
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/11.0.1/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:
> cannot find -lleptonica: No such file or directory
>
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mingw-w64/11.0.1/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld:
> cannot find -ltesseract: No such file or directory
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [mb] Error 1

I don't understand why it tries to find -lleptonica and -ltesseract instead of leptonica and tesseract

Comment: Please re-run your command with the `-x` command-line argument passed to `go build` and look at exact invocations of the C compiler and linker which will be printed.

Comment: @kostix There is a huge output, but at the end i got this:
EOF
mkdir -p $WORK/b001/exe/
cd .
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link -o $WORK/b001/exe/a.out.exe -importcfg $WORK/b001/importcfg.link -buildmode=pie -buildid=fNT-rcO9nbcKQWgyleZc/KS_11tGsrNQITK1qUM8j/mxltrhl0X1o4LfTb7ETF/fNT-rcO9nbcKQWgyleZc -extldflags=-static -extld=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /Users/folium/Library/Caches/go-build/cb/cb49e886672f70f9b98a466c5f1eceb53b2a00abafd1d3587eb63471a979fb98-d

End then the same errors, "No such file or directory" for -lleptonica and -ltesseract

Comment: it is trying to include libraries leptonica and tesseract. The prefix is -I for include.  you need to have these in the in the include path.  If you include these paths using `-ldflags='-I /foo/ld.so'`, it should compile.

Comment: @whitespace, `-I` (capital 'i') adds include paths for C header files, not libraries; the latter is controlled by `-L` (capital el).